# Dynamodb get items based on time and likes

Tags: node.js, database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Currently, I am making a [9gag.com](https://9gag.com) replica, where users can see posts having more than **20 votes** from the last **2 months**, how can I achieve this efficiently?

Here is my current design for **post** table

```
userID | createTime | totalUpvotes | imageUrl | title
```

where userID is the partition key and createTime is the sort key, I also need pagination so finally here is my parameter for fetching the items:

```
const params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    FilterExpression:
      '#createTime >= :_createTime AND #totalUpvotes >= :_votes',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#createTime': 'createTime',
      '#totalUpvotes': 'totalUpvotes'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':_createTime': Date.now() - FEED_TIME_THRESHOLD,
      ':_votes': votes
    },
    Limit: MAX_POST_FETCH
};
if (lastEvaluatedKey) params.ExclusiveStartKey = lastEvaluatedKey;
return db.scan(params).promise();
```

I know **scan** function is not recommended, but I am thinking of using Redis to cache the posts, and re-run the **scan** operation every 20 minutes or so since all users should have seen the same content on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an attribute `popular` with a value that's present only for popular items (i.e. 20+ upvotes). You can use a simple constant as the value. Then create a (sparse) GSI having `popular` as the PK and `createTime` as the SK. You can then query the GSI for popular items with a `createTime` greater than two months ago.

Comment: Thank you, this solution makes sense! And in dynamodb can I update this popular field when updating the totalUpvotes? e.g. while updating totalUpvotes, popular will be 0, 1, 2, etc based on totalUpvotes? Of course, another solution is to fetch the post first to get the totalUpvotes, and then update the fields.

Comment: You’ll want to fetch it first to decide if popular needs to be set. You can use a conditional expression to increment only if the original value is what you just saw, to serialize concurrent writes.